# String concatenation in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this helper to simplify null asserts:

```
object Helpers {
  implicit class NotNullAssert[T](val obj: T) extends AnyVal {
    def ! : T = {
      assert(obj != null); obj
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to use it:

```
import Helpers._

class Name(val first: String, val last: String) {
  val full = first! + " " + last!
}
```

Getting a compilation error:

```
Error:(8, 27) value unary_+ is not a member of String
               val full = "" + first! + " " + last!
```

The same time, the following works:

```
val full = first! //+ " " + last!
```

What is going wrong in the fragment above?

Comment: `first!` is "post-fix notation" and confuses the compiler when used in longer expressions. Try `first.!` and see what happens.

Comment: ... or (first!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix operators tend not to play well with binary infix operators. However, you might want to define `!` as an unary operator that should be used in prefix position:

```
def unary_! : T = {
  assert(obj != null); obj
}
```

Then this here works:

```
val full = !first + " " + !last
```

But please be careful with this, probably nothing good will happen when you try to use it with boxed booleans or other types that support unary `!`. When in doubt, just use `.` or parentheses.

---

An aside about the usage of `.!`-syntax: when using `sys.process`, it's rather common to write `cmd.!` and `cmd.!!`, so keeping your definition and using `.!` wouldn't look "too weird".

Answer (score 1):

With mkString it works:

```
import Helpers._

class Name(val first: String, val last: String) {
  val full = List (first!, last!).mkString (" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you follow the rules in [Prefix, Infix, and Postfix Operations](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#prefix-infix-and-postfix-operations)

```
"" + first! + " " + last!
```

gets parsed as

```
"".+(first).!(+ " ").+(last).!
```

and then it can't find the `unary_+` required for `+ " "`.

This transformation happens at the parsing stage, and so doesn't know anything about what methods are available.